# protect http request using json (android)

Tags: android, mysql, http, phpmyadmin

I am using json request for logging in and displaying messages pertaining to the user .But if I make the same request from the browser it still works. I am using PHP-MYSQL for my App .
I do not have any website so I will need the answer for the app itself.

I am using facebook sdk with android app so I dont have any passwords. I would like to secure the chat msgs between the users and user data profile when it is called.Thats it.

My questions are:

1. How do I make sure the call is made within the app only?
2. How do I secure the call when some tries to copy and paste the code in the browser ?

3.Have timeout for the message created after 10 secs.So the same url and msg cannot be reused.

I have http call like http:/example.com/login=emailId;

get msgs: http:/example.com/getMsgs/user=uiniqueNo;

I have provided the above links as I am using in the app and its working fine but is not secure.
Please suggest me some documents and process.I have checked this link [Protect HTTP request from being called by others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3068916/protect-http-request-from-being-called-by-others)  but it was not clear .Please suggest me any tutorial which has the above requirements . Thanks in Advance.I really appreciate the help.

```
public class CustomizedListView extends Activity {
    // All static variables
    static final String URL = "http://example.com/getmsgs/userno=123";
    // XML node keys
    static final String KEY_SONG = "song"; // parent node
    static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    static final String KEY_ARTIST = "artist";
    static final String KEY_DURATION = "duration";
    static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumb_url";

    ListView list;
    LazyAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        JSONObject json = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL(URL);


        try {
            JSONObject arr2 = json.getJSONObject("feed");
            JSONArray arr = arr2.getJSONArray("entry");

            for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject e1 = arr.getJSONObject(i);

                JSONArray arr3 = e1.getJSONArray("im:image");

                JSONObject arr8 = e1.getJSONObject("im:name");

                JSONObject arr10 = e1.getJSONObject("im:artist");

                    JSONObject e12 = arr3.getJSONObject(0);

            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

            map.put(KEY_THUMB_URL,  e12.getString("label"));

            map.put(KEY_ARTIST, arr8.getString("label"));
            map.put(KEY_TITLE, arr10.getString("label"));
            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            songsList.add(map);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                    "Network communication error!", 5).show();
        }


        list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);

        // Getting adapter by passing xml data ArrayList
        adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, songsList);        
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        // Click event for single list row
        list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {


                HashMap<String, String> o = (HashMap<String, String>) list.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Toast.makeText(CustomizedListView.this, "ID '" + o.get("KEY_TITLE") + "' was clicked.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

            }
        });     
    }   
}
```

In the above code anyone can guess usersno but how do I secure that no 123 in the app and in the php server .So that even if sniffer program is used and and reverse engineered to get code from apk file the data still is protect and encryption should be deep in OS which users cannot break and hence I can decrypt the code in server php and user will have no way to randomly type anything as 123.

```
<?php

$strno=$_GET['strno'];

if (isset($strno))
{
        $connect=mysql_connect("localhost","test","test") or die ('Connection error!!!');
        mysql_select_db("test") or die ('Database error!!!');

    $query=mysql_query("select sno FROM users  where strno='$strno';");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))

    {
        $jsonoutput='{"json":{
            "msg_sub":"'.$row['msg_sub'].'",
            }}';
    }

}

echo trim($jsonoutput);
mysql_close($connect) or die ('Unable to close connection-error!!!');
}

?>
```

Comment: I noticed you have `http://example.com/getmsgs/limit=20/userno=123` as your api endpoint. Can you post the code that is running there also?

Comment: I am on it.Posting it anytime now.

Comment: Added php code too. Its simplified .

Answer (score 1):

Ok there is no ***way*** to actually perfectly protect this system unless you use https to transmit data between your api and your js client.

This is what you do:

1. First create a user login system, username/password table on your database side
2. Next create a form for the user to login
3. Whenever a user tries to access the api your server will check if it has a session set for that user, they will either have to login or pass an existing session id which will grant them access
4. Next is to buy an https certificate that will ensure your data is transmitted securely
5. Now on each request to the api, the server always checks if they user has sent a valid SESSION ID, if not, it will simply redirect them to a login page

This is pretty much the only way you can add security to your system. The most important part is the https cert. Without this, it doesnt matter how good a user/password is, it can still be compromised.

**EDIT**

Here is some sample code to get you started. This code is not tested and its just there to give you an idea. You can read all about sessions [here](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpsessions.php).

```
 <?php

    /*
        like I said earlier, you need to have a "login" screen on your app
        - when the user clicks login it POSTS the request back here
    */

    if(isset($_SESSION['username'])){
        //the username is in the session so it means
        //theyre already logged in
        //not sure what strno is doing but you can do that here

        $strno=$_GET['strno'];

        if (isset($strno))
        {
                $connect=mysql_connect("localhost","test","test") or die ('Connection error!!!');
                mysql_select_db("test") or die ('Database error!!!');

            $query=mysql_query("select sno FROM users  where strno='$strno';");
            while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))

            {
                $jsonoutput='{"json":{
                    "msg_sub":"'.$row['msg_sub'].'",
                    }}';
            }

        }

        echo trim($jsonoutput);
        mysql_close($connect) or die ('Unable to close connection-error!!!');

    }else if(isset($_POST) && isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])){
        //log them in
        //query ur database to see if the user exists
        //if you get a row back then store that row in the session like
        //note: this is just example code

        if(/*user is in database, get the row....*/){
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
        }
    }else{
        die("Access Denied");
    }

?>
```

Comment: Thank You for your response Sir.But I need it regarding the app itself since I dont have a website for the same.Also I have not used session id .Also I did not get create a form for the user to login statement PLease can you provide me the link which would give a sample/example fro the explanation you suggested .I would really appreciate the help.Thanks again Sir.

Comment: I have updated the question too as I am using facebook sdk for login for my app.

Comment: Ok so to make it really simple, if you tried to access `http:/example.com/getMsgs/user=uiniqueNo` but your are NOT authorized to access the api you should not know what `uniqueNo` is. Therefore if you make a request without knowing what `uniqueNo` is, it should redirect yo a login page. After logging in, `session_start()` is called which will create a unique session_id for this user. The next time the user tries to access the api, they will need to pass their session_id on the request. The server will do `session_start()` to resume the session and thus granting access to the app.

Comment: Hello Sir I am using android app is there any work around for session id part as it is for app the description above is for html.Please can you suggest something similar in android calls.

Comment: edit your question to include more android code, I can probably help you better if I can see your code.

Comment: how do I implement sessions in android since there are no pages but activity screens?

Answer (score 0):

There are two options to achieve this. First thing is using `GET` method, you can create a specific params on your server side which you are looking for. For example from your android app you are sending `http://www.my-backend.com/api/test_api?my_secure_code=thisIsTestString` and server returns the right response, but if you send `http://www.my-backend.com/api/test_api?my_secure_code=thatsAnotherString` , the param value you are searching for in the request is not `thisIsTestString`, so you should return error message.

In my opinion the second way to achieve this is better, because using `GET` is not thats ecure in my opinion.It's easier than using `POST`. In that case you will have to send `my_secure_param` as post param, which you can use by typing in your browser (there is still a way to achieve this by browser by installing plugin for post request). So I think the best solution here is to use `POST` request while connection to back-end sending some hashed string using `MD5` or `SHA1` (at least that's the way we are securing connection with our server + some more extras).

**Edit:** Regarding comments, the way you can achieve this is by creating some kind of identification for the specific user on your server, not trusting facebook. It's just a proposal...for example you can get the id user from facebook and create a unique hashed id which you will store in your server and everytime you are sending requests from your app, you have to send that unique id, which will be created in app in the same way used to create it on the server. And you will have to check for that hash everytime someone sends message if that match, if not just return error..and just don't forget, use `POST` requests instead of `GET`! There is no way to achieve something like this without changing some codes in your server's backend.

Comment: Thank You for your response Sir.But I need it regarding the app itself since I dont have a website for the same.PLease can you provide me the link which would give a sample/example fro the explanation you suggested .I would really appreciate the help.Thanks again Sir.

Comment: I have updated the question too as I am using facebook sdk for login for my app.

Comment: are you using another server to deliver messages to the user?

Comment: yes that server stores personal msgs with respect to the app not facebook so how do I secure sending and viewing msgs of other users from browser since the unique user id may be guessed by trial and error.

Comment: To secure the connection from sniffers you can use web sertificates and you should handle trust method in your android app. about reverse engineering on android side, obfuscate your code using proguard, it's build in android so you won't have problem with it.

Comment: are web certificates free and can be used within the app? Sorry Sir I have absolutely no clue regarding the above topic.

Comment: here you can find much more information about ssl and certificates : http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html, and about proguard : http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html

Comment: Thank you sir about ssl security was new and pleasse post another link with simple example so that I can implement in small project.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/net/ssl/HttpsURLConnection.html hope this help

Comment: Thank You again I will try that and keep you posted Sir.